# Understanding the Zellener-Revankar Production Function

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, production-function

I took out a book from my university library called Econometric Modelling with Time Series: Specification Estimation and Testing in an attempt to understand the importance of MLE in Econometrics.

There is a small note mentioning a production function I've never seen before called the **Zellener-Revankar Production Function (ZRPF)**. Its a non-linear production function relating to output, capital and labor defined as:

$$\ln y_t+\alpha y_t=\beta_0+\beta_1 \ln k_t+ \beta_2 \ln l_t + u_t$$

The left hand side makes sense, however the right hand side seems odd. What kind of production it is trying to represent and more fundamentally, how this is mathematically considered a function give that there are two dependents on the left hand side?

Ive looked at the relevant paper work namely:

> - [Estimation of Zellner-Revankar production function revisited
>
>     SK Mishra,
>     Department of Economics,
>     North-Eastern Hill University
>
>     Shillong (India)](http://www.accessecon.com/pubs/EB/2007/Volume3/EB-06C60008A.pdf)
> - [ALTERNATIVE FUNCTIONAL FORMS FOR PRODUCTION,
>     COST AND RETURNS TO SCALE FUNCTIONS
>     by
>     Arnold Zenner and Hang Ryu](http://ageconsearch.umn.edu/record/198658/files/agecon-cal-832.pdf)

Any help would be appreciated in terms of understanding what type of process this is coming to represent would be helpful.

Comment: "there are two dependents on the left hand side" I only see $y_t$, what is the other dependent variable?

Comment: To me, it's the RHS that makes sense: it's just the usual log-linearized Cobb-Douglas form. However, the LHS is a bit baffling. Are you sure there's no stated interpretation of the LHS? E.g. what does the parameter $\alpha$ capture?

Comment: @HerrK thats what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: @denesp I probably used the wrong term, but from what I know about functions, this would not be defined as one.

Comment: @EconJohn Why not? For any positive $\alpha$ the function $f(y) = \ln y + \alpha y$ is a strictly increasing and hence invertible function. So if you say $f(y) = g(k,l)$ then you are implicitly defining $y = f^{-1} \circ g(k,l)$.

Comment: @denesp thank you for the explanation on how this works. Now how does one estimate this?

Comment: @EconJohn I have no clue. If that is your actual question I recommend making a significant edit to your question. It has no answers yet, so large edits are still fine.

Answer (score 3):

Caution: Heavy citing

"In his doctoral dissertation *Revankar* (1967) expounded his generalized
production functions that permit variability to *returns-to-scale* as well as *elasticity of substitution*. In contrast with the production functions that (rather unrealistically) assume the same returns to scale at all levels of output, **Zellner and Revankar (1969)** found a procedure to generalize **any given (neoclassical)** production function with specified *constant* or *variable elasticities of substitution* such that the resulting production function **retains its specification as to the elasticities of substitution** all along but **permits returns- to-scale to vary** with the scale of output. Their Generalized Production Function (GPF) is given as
\begin{equation}
\ Pe^{\theta P} = c^h f^h
\end{equation}
where f is the basic function (e.g. **Cobb-Douglas, CES**, etc) as the
object of generalization, c is the constant of integration and *θ, h*
relate to parameters
associated with the returns-to-scale function. In particular, if the Cobb-Douglas production function is generalized, we have
\begin{equation}
\ Pe ^{\theta P}= AK^{\rho\alpha} L^ {\rho (1- \alpha )} 
\end{equation}. This function is *interesting*
from the viewpoint of **estimation** also. It has to be estimated so as to *maximize* the **likelihood function** since the Least Squares and Max Likelihood estimators of parameters do not coincide. The return to scale function is given by 
\begin{equation}
\rho (P) = \rho /(1 + \theta P) 
\end{equation} . Depending on θ the sign of θ , the returns-to-scale function monotonically increases or decreases with
increase in P. However, as we know, the returns to scale first increases with output, remains more or less constant in a domain and then begins falling. This fact is not captured by the Zellner-Revankar function since it gives us a linear returns-to-scale function."

from **A Brief History of Production Functions** by *SK Mishra* 2007

So, I would guess, the  \begin{equation}  \alpha  \end{equation} parameter 
in your log-linearized function would have something to do with returns-to-scale.

Regarding estimation, I'm way too much of a newb. But this might be something at least similar to what you are looking for: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/3-540-28556-3_2 
**Variable Elasticity of Substitution and Economic
Growth: Theory and Evidence** by 
*Giannis Karagiannis,
Theodore Palivos,
and Chris Papageorgiou*,
2005